# XCTest continueAfterFailure = false no longer stops tests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

While `continueAfterFailure = false` worked earlier for me, it no longer does.
Demo: This little test should stop in `func testExample`, but `func testExample2` is also executed, see the log.

```
import XCTest

final class FailureTests: XCTestCase {
    
    override func setUp() {
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }
    
    override func tearDown() {
    }
    
    func testExample() {
        XCTFail("Test fails as required")
    }
    
    func testExample2() {
        XCTFail("Unexpextedly executed")
    }
    
}
```

Test log:

[image]

What could be the reason? What to do to let it stop again?

Comment: The documentation for `continueAfterFailure` always said that it stops the execution of the current test only, so not sure why you would've expect to prevent the execution of the other tests too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this test case:

```swift
func testExample() {
    XCTFail("first")
    XCTFail("second")
}
```

By default, XCTest keeps going even when an assertion fails. That is, it will report both failures. This is different from the behavior of other xUnit frameworks.

With `continueAfterFailure` set to false, it will stop the test case after the first failure, and not reach the second. But it will continue to run all other test cases.